# Will Yammer work on SharePoint 2016 on premise farm having no internet

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, yammer, internet

I have a SharePoint 2016 on premise farm and want to integrate Yammer. Will it work on server which has no internet access or internet access is always required for Yammer to work on on premise farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/add-the-yammer-embed-widget-to-a-sharepoint-page), yes it should as it is using a Script Editor webpart which would be executed client-side.